# Diameter of graph where $V = \mathbb{N}$ and two vertices are connected if they sum to a square

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory

After watching the Numberphile video [The Square Sum Problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1m7goLCJDY), I explored the idea further and came up with this conjecture.

Let $G$ be a graph where $V(G)=\mathbb{N}$ and $E(G)=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{N}:a+b \space$ is a perfect square$\}$. The diameter of $G$ is $3$.

Exploring finite subgraphs of this with Mathematica seems to suggest the conjecture is true. For example, the shortest path between $1$ and $2$ is $(1,15,34,2)$, and I can confirm that the maximum distance between any two integers $\le 100$ is $3$.

I can also rephrase the conjecture in number-theoretic terms:

$\forall n,m\in\mathbb{N}, \exists x,y\in\mathbb{N}:n+x,x+y,$ and $y+m$ are all perfect squares. This would imply the above conjecture, as it would yield the path $(n, x, y, m)$ for any two vertices $n,m$.

How might one prove this conjecture?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$(1+h)^2-h^2-1=2h,\qquad(1+h)^2-h^2-4=2h-3,$$
so any integer (even or odd) may be written in the form $a^2+b^2-c^2$ for integers $a,b,c$.

In particular, given integers $m,n$ we have integers $a,b,c$ such that $$a^2+b^2-c^2=m+n.$$

Then $m+(a^2-m)$ is a perfect square, $n+(b^2-n)$ is a perfect square, and $$(a^2-m)+(b^2-n)=a^2+b^2-(m+n)=c^2$$ is a perfect square.

Thus we can get from $m$ to $n$ via the sequence:$$m,\quad a^2-m,\quad b^2-n,\quad n.$$

Note this is working over the integers so not quite the same as your question if you only want to consider naturals.